# Queue actions for a plain thread class?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Because I can't catch `RaceOnRCWCleanup` and because I know I'm dirty-programming using COM objects from multiple threads without extra safety. I need to ask:

**Question:** How can I allow other threads to enqueue work items/actions in my worker thread (like Invoke/BeginInvoke for Control) ? Basically another thread should be able to tell `MyThread` "Do this! Do that!" and do **no** action in place of `MyThread`.

I need to use parameters and return values as well. The resources (COM objects) must be used by this one thread only. I thought about creating a Queue of an enum of actions to perform but I'm at a loss of how to add parameters and such. My first design looks like the code below.

---

**Edit:** It is also important for me that the thread object is **simple on the outside**. So I want to call a method like `myThread.Connect();` without thinking of any delegates and stuff. The thread object should use delegates or other techniques in the background. For now I'm using a queue with an extra class that stores the called method, parameters and later the result. Results are delivered via a "finished event". I don't think this is a good way to leave it like that because all "action" calls to the thread are asynchronous.

---

```
public class MyThread
{
    // private

    private enum MyEnum { Connect, Disconnect }
    private Queue<MyEnum> queue = new Queue<MyEnum>();

    private void Run()
    {
        // loops, does work and can regularly check a queue
    }

    // public

    public void Connect(string address, int parameter1, object parameter2)
    {
        // triggers connection to a db or somthing similar
        // internally it queues an action for this thread to perform
    }

    public object Disconnect()
    {
        // triggers disconnect from a db or something similar
        // internally it queues an action for this thread to perform
        // but must wait for result
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        // starts the thread
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        // stops the thread
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are looking for is a Producer - Consumers mechanism where the data stored will be your action to be taken by the thread.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky to build yourself but is usually done with delegates along the following lines:

```
public class MyThread
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<Action> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

    private void Run()
    {
        Action action;
        if (queue.TryDequeue(out action))
            action();
    }

    public void Connect(Action action)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(action);
    }
}
```

Example of using parameters with closures over variables:

```
        var t = new MyThread();
        var myVar = 3;
        t.Connect(delegate()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myVar);
        });
```

If you need to return a value it becomes more tricky :) Your queue would need to be changed to a type that can hold both Action and Func. Then you can add a method like.

```
public void object Connect(Func<object> function)
```

You would also need some sort of thread wait like a ManualResetEvent so the caller of Connect() can wait for the response.

Comment: Delegates would probably be the cleanest way. But how to handle parameters and results? With `Action` you have neither.

Comment: I added an example of how to add in parameter(s). Returning a value becomes more tricky :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to create a single-threaded TPL `TaskScheduler` and queue tasks to it. The built-in `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` *might* be able to guarantee a single fixed thread; you need to look at the documentation to confirm that. If not, [there are others such as `QueuedTaskScheduler`.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As @usr said, creating a single-threaded `TaskScheduler` would be the best option. `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair.ExclusiveScheduler` guarantees that it executes exclusively but not in single thread for all tasks. It could use any thread to execute the `Task`. If you need single fixed thread, you need to implement it yourself.

[Custom scheduler topic in Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows how to implement `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler`. I've modified it to make it "Single Threaded".

```
internal class SingleThreadedTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
{
    private readonly LinkedList<Task> tasks = new LinkedList<Task>(); // protected by lock(_tasks) 

    public SingleThreadedTaskScheduler()
    {
        RunThread();
    }

    protected sealed override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
        lock (tasks)
        {
            tasks.AddLast(task);
            Monitor.Pulse(tasks);
        }
    }

    private void RunThread()
    {
        new Thread(_ =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Task item;
                lock (tasks)
                {
                    if (tasks.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(tasks);
                    }
                    item = tasks.First.Value;
                    tasks.RemoveFirst();
                }
                base.TryExecuteTask(item);
            }
        }).Start();
    }

    protected sealed override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        return false;
    }

    protected sealed override bool TryDequeue(Task task)
    {
        lock (tasks) 
            return tasks.Remove(task);
    }

    public sealed override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }

    protected sealed override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        bool lockTaken = false;
        try
        {
            Monitor.TryEnter(tasks, ref lockTaken);
            if (lockTaken) return tasks;
            else throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lockTaken) Monitor.Exit(tasks);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it as

```
private static readonly TaskScheduler singleThreadedScheduler = new SingleThreadedTaskScheduler();

private static void Main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int index = i;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);//Simulate some work
            Console.WriteLine("Task id {0} Executed in Thread Id {1}", index, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, singleThreadedScheduler);
    }
}
```